# Get nested object in structure in gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have two structures:

```
type GoogleAccount struct {
     Id     uint64
     Token  string
}
```

It represent my custom PostgreSQL object type (i created myself):

```
CREATE TYPE GOOGLE_ACCOUNT AS
(
  id    NUMERIC,
  token TEXT
);
```

And next structure is table in DB:

```
type Client struct {
     IdClient       uint64          `gorm:"primary_key"`
     Name           string
     PhotoUrl       string
     ApprovalNumber uint16
     Phone          string
     Password       string
     HoursOfNotice  int8
     Google         GoogleAccount
}
```

And my custom object nested in type Client and named as `google`. I've tried to read data by the next way:

```
var users model.Client
db.First(&users)
```

But unfortunately I can't read field `google` (have a default value). I don't want to create separate table with google_account, or make this structure as separated fields in client table or packed it as json (created separate entity, because this structure used not only in this table and I'm searching new ways, that get the same result, but more gracefully). The task **is not to simplify the presentation of data in the table**. I need to make the **correct mapping** of the object from postgres to the entity.

Right now I found one solution - implement Scanner to GoogleAccount. But value in the input method is []uint8. As I can suppose, []uint8 can cast to string, and after that I can parse this string. This string (that keep in db) look like `(x,x)` - where x - is value. Is the right way, to parse string and set value to object? Or is way to get this result by ORM?

Is the possible way, to read this data as nested structure object?

Comment: Do you have column named `Id` & `Token`?

Comment: have you tried something yourself to solve it... please post of the many tries or describe a few to show effort.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a separate table for your separate data structure? Why not put Google ID and token directly in the Client struct then, instead of creating a separate entity which you don't want? Don't normalize things that you don't want normalized?

Comment: @aerokite Yes, in nested field `google` which represent himself a separate structure

Comment: @G_V I just want to use all possibility of PostresSQL. I created separate entity, because this structure used not only in this table. And my decision - it is not denormalization. Merely I'm using new ways, that get the same result, but more gracefully

Comment: @ZF007 Right now I found one solution - implement Scanner to `GoogleAccount`. But value in the input method is []uint8. I've tried to make object from byte, but it was without result

Comment: @KirillZyusko... add the info from your trail not in comment but ad it to the question itself. Its useful information that is now overlooked by others. Good to see effort ;-) (I did triage review your question.. not an expert on your topic... so I look at grammer, formatting and makes the content sense in general).

Comment: @KirillZyusko - How is it more graceful? Why can't you get GoogleAccount fields directly from the Client to which it is tied? If you need a separate table for the data but don't make one, how is that not denormalization? What does graceful mean in this context? New ways?You can't use a term to explain the definition of a term and expect us to know what you're thinking. It really helps to write out what you want, what you've tried, what you don't want and why.

Comment: @G_V Yeah, of course I can separate this data in client table and don't create new type of data. But here is small example, that described a problem with reading object from database to nested object in structure. Big difference between separate field in table or make it as object type I don't see (in the performance angle). Separate table - I want use this field not only in this table, the same it will be use in company table. If create separate table I need to keep pairs id_client and id_company, and one from this always will be null. At addition - performance of 2 query in db will be always

Comment: @G_V more costly, than one query with directly data in table. It's obviously. From point of view traditional SQL database this way looks like "undesired" (made new data type). But I repeat himself again - I just want to try new way. And if Postgres it allow, why i shouldn't to try it? In this example I just wanna to logically group data. Personally for me structure of `client.google.id` looks more suitable, than `client.google_id`. It's a matter of habit. And finally: separate fields in db it's normalization (in my case), but grouped the same data in one field (just object) - denormalization?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/q2DFAqyyrkP . Will it work?

Comment: @aerokite It will work, if table contain field `Id` and `Token` as usually fields of table. But I have an object type. The task is not to simplify the presentation of data in the table. I need to make the correct mapping of the object from postgres to the entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now I found one solution - implement **Scanner** to `GoogleAccount`. At input of the `Scan` method I got `[]uint8`, that I cast to string and parse in the end. This string (that keeping in db) look like `(x,x)` - where `x` - is value. Of course, it is not correct way to achieve my goal. But I couldn't found other solution.

I **highly recommended** use classical binding by relationship or simple keeping these fields in table as simplest value (not as object).

But if you would like to experiment with nested object in table, you can look at my realization, maybe it would be useful for you:

```
type Client struct {
    // many others fields
    Google          GoogleAccount   `json:"google"`
}

type GoogleAccount struct {
    Id      uint64      `json:"id"`
    Token   string      `json:"token"`
}

func (google GoogleAccount) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return "(" + strconv.FormatUint(google.Id, 10) + "," + google.Token + ")", nil
}

func (google *GoogleAccount) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    values := utils.GetValuesFromObject(value)
    google.Id, _ = strconv.ParseUint(values[0], 10, 64)
    google.Token = values[1]
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Next time, don't just put a link to your repo. Add the actual code here as well. Your link is broken.

Comment: @LucioMollinedo thank you for your comment. I added code snippet.

Comment: Holy smokes, the issue I had was putting a pointer in the method for `Value()`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you'll want to do two things with what you have: (1) update the model so you have the right relationship binding, and (2) use the `.Preload()` method if you're trying to get it to associate the data on read.

**Model Changes**

Gorm automatically infers relationships based on the name of the attributes in your struct and the name of the referenced struct. The problem is that `Google` attribute of type `GoogleAccount` isn't associating because gorm is looking for a `type Google struct`.

You're also missing a foreign key on `GoogleAccount`. How would the ORM know which `GoogleAccount` to associate with which `Client`? You should add a `ClientId` to your `GoogleAccount` struct definition.

Also, I would change the primary keys you're using to type `uint` since that's what gorm defaults to (unless you have a good reason not to use it)

If I were you, I would change my struct definitions to the following:

```
type Client struct {
     IdClient       uint            `gorm:"primary_key"`
     Name           string
     PhotoUrl       string
     ApprovalNumber uint16
     Phone          string
     Password       string
     HoursOfNotice  int8
     GoogleAccount  GoogleAccount    // Change this to `GoogleAccount`, the same name of your struct
}

type GoogleAccount struct {
     Id             uint
     ClientId       uint             // Foreign key
     Token          string
}
```

For more information on this, take a look at the associations documentation here: http://gorm.io/associations.html#has-one

**Preloading associations**

Now that you actually have them properly related, you can `.Preload()` get the nested object you want:

```
db.Preload("GoogleAccount").First(&user)
```

Using `.Preload()` will populate the `user.GoogleAccount` attribute with the correctly associated `GoogleAccount` based on the `ClientId`.

For more information on this, take a look at the preloading documentation: http://gorm.io/crud.html#preloading-eager-loading

Comment: Thanks, it works when GoogleAccount is table. But in my case GoogleAccount is ObjectType in Posgres

`CREATE TYPE GOOGLE_ACCOUNT AS
(
  id    NUMERIC,
  token TEXT
);`

And I would like to not separate this type in other table.

Comment: @Kirill I had the same situation, however I used nested JSON. but I have no idea how to use custom types in postgresql with gorm!