# Retrieving arbitrary data into nested object with ORM

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, sqlx, go-pg

I am attempting to develop an api in go, to allow the user to specify an arbitrary data structure, and easily set up endpoints that perform CRUD operations on an auto generated postgres database, based on the structure that they define.

For now, I have been using gorm, and am able to have a database automatically generated based on a user-defined set of structs, that support all types of relations (has one, one to many, etc.). I am also able to insert into the generated database, when JSON is sent in through the endpoints.

The issue I have discovered, is when I try to receive the data. It seems where many of the go ORMs fall short on, is mapping data from all tables back into the nested structs of the parent struct.

For example, if the user defines:

```
type Member struct {
    ID          string      
    FirstName   string      
    Hometown    Hometown    `gorm:"ForeignKey:MemberRefer"`
}

type Hometown struct {
    ID              string
    City            string
    Province        string
    MemberRefer     string
}
```

The database creates the tables:

Members

- id
- first_name

Hometowns

- id
- city
- province
- member_refer

However, when retrieving the data, all that is mapped back is:

```
{
    "id": "dc2bb591-506f-40a5-a141-bdc0c8410ba1",
    "name": "Kevin Krishna",
    "hometown": {
        "id": "",
        "city": "",
        "province": ""
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a go orm that supports this kind of behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 sec google search showed me the answer:

> Preloading associations
>
> Now that you actually have them properly related, you can .Preload() get the nested object you want:
> db.Preload("GoogleAccount").First(&user)

[Get nested object in structure in gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460450/get-nested-object-in-structure-in-gorm)

https://www.google.com/search?q=gorm+nested+struct+golang

Comment: Thanks so much. Yeah when I was researching before, I saw that "gorm preloading doesn't support joins", and interpreted that as if it wouldn't work for joining multiple tables.